# Prevent WCF exposing my whole class?

Tags: c#, wcf, architecture

I've just begun learning WCF, and I'm coming from a total non-web background.

I have built a 3-tier desktop application, which compiles into one exe, which runs locally.

Now I want to move the whole business logics layer to a centric server, and make the GUI a client application.

As far as I understand, WCF should be my solution, as indeed, it helped me achieved what I wanted.

I mange to run remote functions, which is the basic of what I need.

My problem now, is that I don't quite understand the *architecture*.

For example, one of my services, returns a data type (class), from my Business Logics layer.

This class automatically becomes available to the client through the WCF mechanism.

But the problem is, this class contains some methods, which i definitely do not want to expose to the client.

For example a Save method (saves to the db).

Further more, sometimes I don't even want to allow the client to change all the properties of the class, since this class might be sent to one of my services.

I do not want to re-validate the class instance in the service.

What should I do? Should I build another layer, restricted version of the Business Logics, which I expose to the client? Or is there any way expose only part of my class to the client, without restricting the server it self?

I know this is a basic question, but honestly i've searched a lot before asking here. My problem is I don't quite know what to search.

My second question is then, do you have any recommendation for any resource that can explain me this architecture...?

Comment: I think you will be better served abstracting an data transfer object layer. It's a more flexible approach, and more portable if you need to switch away from wcf.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Typically, if you want to encapsulate your business layer, you would not want to expose the business objects directly.  This is because you now have a de-coupled client and you don't necessarily want to have to update the client every time the business logic/properties change.

This is where [Data Transfer Objects (DTO)](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html) come into play nicely.  Usually, you want to have control over your contract (data and methods) that you expose.  Therefore, you would explicitly make other objects (DTOs) that make up the transfer layer.  Then, you can safely change your client and server code independently (as long as both still fulfill the contract objects).

This usually requires a little more mapping (before you send or receive on each side) but it is often worth it.

For WCF, your interfaces and classes marked with `[ServiceContract]` and your classes marked with `[DataContract]` usually make up this transfer layer.

Comment: `[DataContract]` is the way you tell WCF what to serialize/deserialize for exposed method parameters.  See more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

In WCF to expose method to client you have to mark it with OperationContractAttribute. So if you don't want clients to use your Save method, just don't mark them with with this attribute.

More info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicecontractattribute.aspx

Pretty much same thing with properties, but different attribute: DataMemberAttribute. If you don't wont client to see it, just don't mark them with it ([DataMember attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute.aspx))

Answer (score 0):

> But the problem is, this class contains some methods, which i definitely do not want to expose to the client.

Are you able to provide an example of your class and interface code? If so I'm sure you might be able to get more specific answers.

> For example a Save method (saves to the db).

One possible approach would be to separate your class into 2 classes. Define the properties in the first class and then use that class as the base class of your second class. Then use the second class to define the methods. This would allow you to return only the properties while allowing you to keep your code DRY.

> Further more, sometimes I don't even want to allow the client to change all the properties of the class, since this class might be sent to one of my services.
>   I do not want to re-validate the class instance in the service.

While you are able to define logic in the get and set methods for each property I would highly recommend revalidating any input received between services simply because any future changes or errors in one service could potentially lead to larger problems across your application. In addition this also helps to ensure your application is more secure against any potential attacks.

> Should I build another layer, restricted version of the Business Logics, which I expose to the client? Or is there any way expose only part of my class to the client, without restricting the server it self?

I agree with the above answers that you should be able to limit access to the different properties and methods using the data and method attributes within your interfaces.

> My second question is then, do you have any recommendation for any resource that can explain me this architecture...?

If you are looking for inexpensive but highly valuable video based training I've found the courses that Pluralsight offers to be quite good for both architecture as well as WFC services (btw, I am not associated with them, just enjoyed their training).